# Are Psychics arcane casters? Can they prestige into Dragon Disciples and do they suffer Spell Failure?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, prestige-class, psychic-class, occult-magic

Nowhere on the Psychic section does it state that Psychics are arcane or divine casters.

As such, it's not clear if they suffer spell failure, let alone whether or not they can prestige into Dragon Disciple.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### A psychic uses psychic magic.

This does not appear on the *spellcasting* ability, because it later appears on the **Psychic Spells** class ability, few pages later (*Occult Adventures*, page 69):

> **Psychic Spells**
>
> Psychics gain access to the following spells. Many of these spells are found in the Core Rulebook; the spells marked with an asterisk (*) appear in Chapter 4 of this book, and those that are found elsewhere are marked with superscript abbreviations denoting their source. **The psychic casts all spells as psychic spells**.

### A psychic cannot qualify for the Dragon Disciple prestige class.

At least, not without taking levels on another class that grants *arcane spellcasting*. This is because [Psychic Magic](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/occultAdventures/psychicMagic.html) is different from *arcane* and *divine* magic.

> **Psychic Magic**
>
> Wizards study ancient tomes to unlock arcane secrets of the universe, and clerics pray to distant deities to grant them divine power. Yet there is a third, more esoteric kind of magic, connected to every creature's composite being, from the conscious mind to the deepest desire, from the life force to the spirit, from the very soul to the cosmic self. **This third type of magic is psychic magic**.

That said, psychic spells do not use Somatic Components, which is necessary for the *Arcane Spell Failure* mechanic to work:

> Instead of verbal and somatic components, all psychic spells have components related to the caster's inner being. The two psychic components are called emotion components and thought components.

### Psychic spellcasters do not suffer Spell Failure

The rule for **Spell Failure** is exclusive to arcane casters. Since psychic spells are not arcane, psychic spellcasters do not suffer any penalties on their spells from wearing armor.

> Casting an Arcane Spell in Armor: **A character who casts an arcane spell while wearing armor must usually make an arcane spell failure check**. The number in the Arcane Spell Failure Chance column on Table: Armor and Shields is the percentage chance that the spell fails and is ruined. If the spell lacks a somatic component, however, it can be cast with no chance of arcane spell failure.

Comment: You could also point out that Psychic spellcasting also does not use Somatic components, which is generally the portion of spellcasting that armor affects

Answer (score -1):

As you put occult adventures into your tags I take it it is the psychic from there (there are a few other types of psychics around already). Now we have to look at the wordings: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/psychic for the psyhic itself and the dragon disciple class: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/core-rulebook/dragon-disciple

- Type of spellcaster: Psychics don't mention being aracane or divine casters so are clearly neither. Although their spells seem to be the same as the arcane caster ones.
- Spell failure: As stated above as being neither and nothing mentioned they don't suffer spell failure rules as arcane casters do.
- The dragon disciple is a problem. You need to be able to cast level 1 arcane spells without preparation. Now if we take it by the word psychics can't become disciples as they don't have the arcane spell list but a psychic spell list. BUT when we take into consideration that the psychic spell list contains magic missile, .... so clearly things that also the arcane spell list has one can argue that they are similar enough (as they also dont need to prepare spells like sorcerers and use spells similar to arcane ones), so that you CAN substitute the psychic spells for the arcane ones. But that would depend on the GM (as by the word its a clear no).

Comment: *Type of spellcaster: Psychics don't mention being aracane or divine casters so are clearly neither. Although their spells seem to be the same as the arcane caster ones.* Actually it does, on page 69: **"The psychic casts all spells as psychic spells."**