# Are mindblades prone to spell failure?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

As mindblades use psychic spells and the appropriate answer to the normal situation here about psychics [Are Psychics arcane casters? Can they prestige into Dragon Disciples and do they suffer Spell Failure?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71879/are-psychics-arcane-casters-can-they-prestige-into-dragon-disciples-and-do-they) I would say they suffer not from arcane spell failure.

I am a bit unsure though as they still have the light armor ability and that it eliminates arcane failure while wearing light armor.

So: Are mindblades prone to spell failure?

Comment: This is the [Mindblade](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/archetypes/paizo-magus-archetypes/mindblade-magus-archetype/) magus archetype, right?

Comment: @carcer  yes exactly that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No, since psychic spells aren't prone to arcane spell failure

As identified in your linked question, psychic spellcasting doesn't suffer the arcane spell failure chance - because a psychic spell is not an arcane spell. A Mindblade magus casts their spells as psychic spells, not arcane ones, so such spells would never be subject to arcane spell failure. Further supporting this, [psychic spells never have somatic components anyway](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/psychic-magic/#Components):

> Therefore, psychic spells never have verbal or somatic components, and have only expensive material components.

And arcane spell failure chance, even if it weren't specifically scoped to arcane spells, [only affects spells with a somatic component](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/armor/#TOC-Arcane-Spell-Failure-Chance):

> If the spell lacks a somatic component, however, it can be cast with no chance of arcane spell failure.

So there's no way a psychic spell could be affected by arcane spell failure.

The Mindblade archetype doesn't alter or replace the basic proficiencies granted by the magus class, so it does still include the mention that the caster ignores arcane spell failure chance due to light armour for magus spells. As written, though, that particular feature is redundant for the Mindblade, and can be ignored.

It might be that it passes unmentioned due to an oversight in the Mindblade's description - or simply for brevity, since it makes no functional change to the Mindblade's abilities and you can save some wordcount by leaving it unchanged. Either way, you shouldn't read anything into the fact that it's unchanged by the archtype - a Mindblade shouldn't have to worry about arcane spell failure.

Comment: This checks out because Psychic spellcasters do not use somatic components (the portion that is ostensibly affected by armor, based on Still Spell)

Comment: @Ifusaso good point!